# Interpolation with for loop in subelement of a resource where the resource itself is using for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

For example here is a resource (very simplified) being deployed with for_each (the for_each isnt where Im having problems, I can do that all day - its trying to get the data in the ovf_network_map correctly interpolated is where Im having problems):

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vmFromLocalOvf" {
  for_each = var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms
  ...snip...
  ovf_deploy {
    local_ovf_path = "cucm_11.5_vmv8_v1.1.ovf"        
    ovf_network_map = {
      for net in ["INSIDE", "OUTSIDE"]:
      "eth${count.index}" => data.vsphere_network.net.id
    }
```

For this simplified example, the goal there is to end up where ovf_network_map contains { "eth0" = data.vsphere_network.INSIDE.id, "eth1" = data.vsphere_network.OUTSIDE.id }
(obviously, that data objects will be further interpolated there, but hopefully the issue comes across here of what Im trying to accomplish).

There are 2 errors:
`The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.`
also
`A data resource "vsphere_network" "net" has not been declared`, Obviously my interpolation there is wrong.  Hopefully the interpolation I need here is possible - Im probably going about this the wrong way -  any ideas?

**Edit to add:** Ive been able to figure out the numeric counting for eth0, eth1 with this: `eth${index(slice(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key], 3, length(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key]) - 1), net)}" => data.vsphere_network.net.id`

So now all thats left - im stuck with trying to "double" interpolate the "net" there in `data.vsphere_network.net.id` as I get error `A data resource "vsphere_network" "net" has not been declared`

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a **count** variable or a corresponding **count.index** in a **for_each**, so this can't work:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vmFromLocalOvf" {
  for_each = var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms
  ...snip...
  ovf_deploy {
    local_ovf_path = "cucm_11.5_vmv8_v1.1.ovf"        
    ovf_network_map = {
      for net in ["INSIDE", "OUTSIDE"]:
      "eth${count.index}" => data.vsphere_network.net.id
    }
```

It is possible to get a map from indexes to values as follows and then use **each.key** as you would have used **count.index**:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vmFromLocalOvf" {
  for_each = zipmap(
    range(length(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms)),
    var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms
  )
  ...snip...
  ovf_deploy {
    local_ovf_path = "cucm_11.5_vmv8_v1.1.ovf"        
    ovf_network_map = {
      for net in ["INSIDE", "OUTSIDE"]:
      "eth${each.key}" => data.vsphere_network.net.id
    }
```

Comment: this is helpful - while I cant use it as is right now since im already dependent on each.key as the name of my VM (I guess I simplified it too much there), what you have there helps - Ill try to work out something thanks.  1 thing, I dont think we can interpolate the .net. there directly for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Alain had the right idea on zipmap.  But instead of a double interpolation (which isnt supported) I had to abstract my data out into a locals{} variable and thats where the zipmap resided:

```
data "vsphere_network" "networks" {
  count                           = length(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].networks)
  name                            = "CUST-${substr(var.customer, 5, length(var.customer) - 4)}-UC-${var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].networks[count.index]}"
  datacenter_id                   = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
  distributed_virtual_switch_uuid = data.vsphere_distributed_virtual_switch.dvs.id
}
locals {
  netids = zipmap(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].networks, data.vsphere_network.networks.*.id)
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vmFromLocalOvf" {
  for_each = var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms
  name     = "${substr(var.customer, 0, 4)}-${each.key}"
  ovf_deploy {
    local_ovf_path = "ov/${var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key].1}"
    ovf_network_map = {
      for net in slice(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key], 3, length(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key]) - 1) :
      "eth${index(slice(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key], 3, length(var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key]) - 1), net)}" => local.netids[net]
    }
  }
  vapp {
    properties = {
      "DeploymentOption.value" = var.customers[var.customer][var.idc].vms[each.key].2
    }
  }
}
```

and